# Show responsive table in mobile application in a card style

Tags: html, mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I have a responsive table in html code that shows in mobile application correctly,
but I want to showing each row of table in one card with all of each details of each row, not in a row like web . but I need just in mobile style.

how do I do?

```
  <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                <table id="basic-datatables" class="display table table-striped table-hover table-bordered ">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Pic</th>
                                            <th>Mom</th>
                                            <th>Score</th>
                                            <th>Best Sell</th>
                                            <th>Meal Number</th>
                                            <th>State</th>
                                            <th>Min Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img class="img-thumbnail" src="img/default.jpg" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td>Flore</td>
                                            <td>
                                                200
                                                <span>
                                                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>61+</td>
                                            <td>700</td>
                                            <td>Bostanli</td>
                                            <td>120 TL</td>
                                        </tr>
                                       
                                       
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```